# Error in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 when opening solution (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 this morning and in my main web solution I now get the following warning when I open it. I also get this warning when I open typescript files and I can no longer comment and uncomment code through the shortcut or toolbar. I also no longer have IntelliSense etc...

[image: vs2015u3exception]

In the xml file it says the following:

```
 <entry>
    <record>851</record>
    <time>2016/07/04 11:40:28.893</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript&apos; Description: Field not found: &apos;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Options.ServiceFeatureOnOffOptions.ClosedFileDiagnostic&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: &apos;Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Shared.Options.ServiceFeatureOnOffOptions.ClosedFileDiagnostic&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131511</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>852</record>
    <time>2016/07/04 11:40:28.895</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral](null)</description>
    <guid>{2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}</guid>
    <hr>80131511</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

What I have tried:

- Repairing Update 3
- Reinstalling TypeScript and removing older versions I had installed: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593
- devenv.exe /updateconfiguration & devenv.exe /clearcache
- Deleting %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
- Updating project typescript version to 1.8
- Setting path environment variable of typescript to 1.8 instead of 1.0

So now my Visual Studio tells me I have TypeScript version 1.8.30 installed.
[image]
But in my Programs and Features I only have verison 1.8.6.0 installed (which is the latest).
[image: programsandfeaturestypescript]

Only thing that is left to do is reinstall Visual Studio itself.

Any ideas, suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I've had similar but not exact issues.  Here's what I had to do to get things restored.  Uninstall VS, remove all references in local and remote folder to anything that says Visual Studio, including Visual Studio common, next delete all Programs Folder Visual Studio (folders).  Then check to see if there's any typescript installs left and remove those.  Start the reinstall again to get a complete fresh install.  It worked for me after about 4 days of doing what you're doing now.

Comment: @JohnPeters Brr, that's kind of my last resort here. But thanks for the detailed info!

Comment: Oh yes one other thing, after I did the super clean install, I still had to repair it one time afterward, then everything worked. It was a mess for me.

Comment: This solved it, I used Visual Studio Uninstaller from Microsoft to remove most of the Visual Studio stuff: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller I still had to remove some typescript stuff manually, but oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by:

- uninstalling Visual Studio with [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller)
  created by microsoft.
- removed any leftover typescript installs (In Add/Remove software)
- removed the TypeScript SDK's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript
- running CCleaner (Cleaner and Registry)

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

**If you do NOT want go the last resort route by doing a full wipe of all-things-VS, try this instead:**

1. remove existing typescript installations (in Add/Remove as usual)
2. install another version
3. Try opening an application that was giving you the error

If the error persists, go back to step 1 and install another version (up or down a notch)

If the error is gone, WIN!!!

Unfortunately for me this meant installing 2.0.2 BETA instead of 2.0.3 - No idea why they jump around like they do, but 1.8.4 caused the error, 2.0.3 caused the error, but 2.0.2 did not. 2.0.2 is only available in beta apparently.

It's a stop gap. I might have to deal with some unintended side effects or end up doing the full re-install later, but so far so good and it only took a few minutes of trial and error. I recommend starting with 2.0.2 beta if you're not more averse to it than me because so far, it's working like a charm and I'll just upgrade when 2.0.4 comes out or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else seeing this after installing typescript 2.0.0, i simply had to

- removed any leftover typescript installs (In Add/Remove software)
- removed the TypeScript SDK's in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

and restart visual studio, then the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a solved issue but answers in here didnt do the trick for me, this solved my issue tho;

> Somehow, you have ended up installing VS without the full version of
>   our update 3 installer (the msi above:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808016), and instead got an
>   older version depending on the feed/settings you used.  After that,
>   either VS auto-updated the extension part of the tools from the
>   gallery (or you manually updated from the gallery) which does not
>   include full version of our tools, only the extension part.  The
>   extension part depends an interfaces assembly that would normally have
>   been installed in the VS installer during setup.
>
> Try running the full msi installer from the link above.  that should
>   update the interfaces assembly that was not previously updated.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94dbabd8-ed24-48f4-a56b-cda702574207/visual-studio-2015-appinsights-error-messages?forum=ApplicationInsights